# XML feed in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm using drupal 7 with [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module.

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/4658/drupal-how-to-create-a-feed-importer-and-select-the-fetcher-as-http-fetcher) to try to create nodes with the feed but it didn't work.

Here is the feed : https://cb1-demo-fr-staffing.luceosolutions.com/openrest/requisitions/active
Does anyone know why ?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Too vague, you need to provide more information. Maybe some screen shots of your Feeds settings? Lets see what your mapping looks like

Comment: @DMAC I've added screen shots of the Module. Hope it's more clear

Comment: You do not have xpath parser inside your mapping. Flush all caches then go back to your `parser` settings and click xpath XML parser. Inside your mapping your source should be `xpathparser:0` and then you can map it to what field it should go to. Then when you go to `/import` there should be a dropdown called `XPATH PARSER SETTINGS` click on that, then for the context put `//requisition` as your context. Then mapp the XML field in the XML file to said field. Example: title = `job_id`, and Body = `rendered_job_posting`

Comment: As long as you follow the tutorial it should get you 90% of the way there. The Xpathparser is a little confusing at first, but basically in your mapping map all the xpathparser values to your values within your Content type your importing too. Then on `/import` it should be where you assign your XML field values from the feed to said Xpathparser values, AKA your CT fields. I can't post an answer or I would provide screenshots

Comment: @DMAC It worked !!!!!!!!! Thank you very much, could you please put your comments as an answer so i can select it as the right answer, if anyone needed help for this in the futur ! Many thanks again !

Comment: Glad to hear it. I can't answer the question because the question was put on hold as it was flagged `too broad` by @Clive. No biggie :P

Comment: @DMAC Go for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have `xpath parser` inside your mapping, which is required for the XML feed you are using, as it is in XML format.

The Xpathparser is a little confusing at first, but basically in your mapping, map all the *XPath parser* values to your values within your Content type you're importing too. 
Then on `/import` it should be where you assign your XML field values from the feed to said Xpathparser values, AKA your CT fields.

Flush all caches then go back to your parser settings and click **XPath XML parser**.

[image]

Inside your mapping your source should be `xpathparser:0` and then you can map it to what field it should go to from your associated CT(set in **Node processor settings**). Do this for ever field from your CT which you want a value coming into.

[image]

Then when you go to `/import` there should be a dropdown called `XPATH PARSER SETTINGS` click on that. there will be a context field, give the context field the value of `//requisition`. (Optionally you can set this up on the Feeds settings under the **Xpath XML parser Settings** IF you have already set up your mapping)

[image]

The context is  where you want the feeds importer to start importing tag data from. You want the context to be `//requisition` so you can grab the tag values from within it. (example job_id). Then map the XML field in the XML file to said field.

Example: title = `job_id`, and Body = `rendered_job_posting`.

[image]